# How to make one variable true at a time using ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-ng-if

**Code :**

```
 <app-part [search]='search' *ngIf="isPart"></app-part>  
    <app-partlist [search]='search' *ngIf="isPartList"></app-partlist>
```

**Todo :**

- To make visible only one of the two components.

In below code both tabs are true at a time,...I am trying to do open one tab at a time

```
    getItem(search: Search) {
    if (search.item.startsWith("A") || search.item.startsWith("H") || search.item.startsWith("N") || search.item.startsWith("Q") || search.item.startsWith("R") && search.item.length == 11) {
      this.isPart = true
    }
    else if (search.item.startsWith("Z") || search.item.startsWith("V") || search.item.startsWith("X") || search.item.startsWith("G") && search.item.length == 9) {
      this.isPartList = true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign false when you are making other variable as true.

```
   getItem(search: Search) {
        if (search.item.startsWith("A") || search.item.startsWith("H") || search.item.startsWith("N") || search.item.startsWith("Q") || search.item.startsWith("R") && search.item.length == 11) {
          this.isPart = true;
          this.isPartList = false;
        }
        else if (search.item.startsWith("Z") || search.item.startsWith("V") || search.item.startsWith("X") || search.item.startsWith("G") && search.item.length == 9) {
          this.isPartList = true
          this.isPart = false;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will open only one tab at a time (using single variable), 
In this case :

- both components dom rendering is dependent on `isPart` variable. And at a time, only one is true.
- if you want two different variable, then other answer is your required case.

```
<app-part [search]='search' *ngIf="isPart"></app-part>  
        <app-partlist [search]='search' *ngIf="!isPart"></app-partlist>
```

Answer (score 0):

use only one prop and ngIfElse

```
<app-part [search]='search' *ngIf="isPart; else partList"></app-part>
<ng-template #partList>
    <app-partlist [search]='search'></app-partlist>
</ng-template>
```

And getItem:

```
getItem(search: Search) {
    if (search.item.startsWith("A") || search.item.startsWith("H") || search.item.startsWith("N") || search.item.startsWith("Q") || search.item.startsWith("R") && search.item.length == 11) {
      this.isPart = true
    } else if (search.item.startsWith("Z") || search.item.startsWith("V") || search.item.startsWith("X") || search.item.startsWith("G") && search.item.length == 9) {
      this.isPart = false
    }
}
```

If you still need to resove multiple types, you can use string identifiers:

```
<app-part [search]='search' *ngIf="contnetType === 'part'"></app-part>
<app-partlist [search]='search' *ngIf="contnetType === 'list'"></app-partlist>
```

.

```
getItem(search: Search) {
    if (search.item.startsWith("A") || search.item.startsWith("H") || search.item.startsWith("N") || search.item.startsWith("Q") || search.item.startsWith("R") && search.item.length == 11) {
      this.contentType = "part";
    } else if (search.item.startsWith("Z") || search.item.startsWith("V") || search.item.startsWith("X") || search.item.startsWith("G") && search.item.length == 9) {
      this.contentType = "list";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..I tried this but in my case when I open first tab, second time, data is disappearing